# Frozen pygobject application and theming

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pygobject

I have almost finished porting an application of mine from py27 & pyGTK to py33 & pyGObject

I am also using cx_freeze to ... "freeze" the application for portability. 
The problem I am now facing is surrounding theming.

The pygobject installer for windows put the GTK3 runtime into the site-package location & appends that to the system PATH variable ( C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome )

Now when I package the entire project up and run it on the machine it was bundled on everything appears fine. I move it onto a machine that does not have python installed and it looks ... different. Now different doesn't mean bad (although the font it has reverted to is poor and would have to change) but I would like to understand why.

C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome\etc\gtk-3.0\settings.ini

> [Settings]
>   gtk-theme-name = Adwaita
>   ...

And the appearance seems to be "Adwaita".
Now the bundled/cx_freeze version has the key libraries/directories (inc share/themes...) copied into the working directory, but no theming is applied. 
I have even copied the entire C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome\ directory into the working directory to see if it does anything & to ensure I don't miss anything ... I havn't

This is the odd part. As mentioned on my machine it is fine. IF I copy the ENTIRE 
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome\ into the working directory, again its fine. 
If I then do something like:

C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome\ --> C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome1

I get the same visual change on my machine as others with no python install. 
This points towards there is still some infomation/pointers/absolute reference to a GTK_DATA_PREFIX that is C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\gnome\  such that any other location isn't parsed.

Does anyone know what else is needed to allow a frozen pygobject application to load themes?

--edit--

Bit closer. Not only themes are effected but also schemas ( in my case file chooser).

I have cx_freeze dumping all the DLL/pyd into a sub folder (bin) and I have set some is.environ variables to allow this to work (matplotlib data, GI_typedef and extended path to ./bin)

As mentioned themes and schemas do t work BUT if I copy everything from bin to the root it works.

I shortlisted it to bin/etc/ and bin/share/gtk-3.0/schemas

This points to some additional variables are needed

```
if getattr(sys,'frozen',False):
    # if trap for frozen script wrapping
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\library.zip'))

    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\tcl')
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\tk')
    os.environ['MATPLOTLIBDATA'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\mpl-data')
    os.environ['GI_TYPELIB_PATH'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\lib\girepository-1.0')
    os.environ['GTK_HOME'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin')
    os.environ['GTK_BASEPATH'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin')
    os.environ['GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\share\glib-2.0')
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin')
```

Would anyone happen to know the additional variables?

Comment: If no-one knows the answer (I don't), you could remove the files you copied from `site-packages/gnome/`, one-by-one until the theme changes. That should tell you what it's using, and then you can just copy those files. You might be able to push improvements back into cx_Freeze - I think more people use it with Qt than with Gtk.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have added a bit more information. Its more downto location it seems & ... hopefully, there is another variable

Comment: @Naib I was wondering if you could share your build process with me. Since I am also trying to package my app for windows and definitely could use some of your experience.

Comment: python in general or py+gtk or py+qt